# Reset with jquery button that does not have a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have built a game and I am wondering if I can reset the game with a button. I have created the game and built the button into the javascript and set it up for a function but I am unsure of what function will reset the entire game board. I have tried using  $(":reset") and alternating it to use var win and grid.item, but it is not working. How should I go about resetting the grid and var win?

```js
var win = parseInt(Math.random() * 9) + 1
var i = 1;
$('.grid-item').each(function() {
  $(this).data('slot', i++);
});

$('.grid-item').click(function() {
  if ($(this).data('slot') == win) {
    $(this).addClass('yes');
    $("H3").append("<H3>Congrats, You have won!</H3>");


  } else {
    $(this).addClass('no');
  }
});

$('button').click(function() {

});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 1px;
}

.grid-item.no {
  background-image: url(https://s22.postimg.cc/yo9soxxz5/kisspng-computer-icons-x-mark-check-mark-clip-art-red-x-5ac2fb83.png);
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.grid-item.yes {
  background-image: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/papirus-team/papirus-apps/512/emerald-theme-manager-icon-icon.png);
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

H3 {
  color: green;
}

button {
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid black;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hidden Gem!</title>



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <H1>Hidden Gem Game!</H1><br/>
  <div class='grid'>
    <div class='grid-item'></div>
    <div class='grid-item'></div>
    <div class='grid-item'></div><br/>
    <div class='grid-item'></div>
    <div class='grid-item'></div>
    <div class='grid-item'></div><br/>
    <div class='grid-item'></div>
    <div class='grid-item'></div>
    <div class='grid-item'></div>
  </div>
  <H3></H3>
  <br/>
  <H2>Click on the boxes to find the hidden gem.</H2>


  <button type="button">Play Again</button>



  <script src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Remove classes from the clicked divs and clear h3

Answer (score 0):

You should remove all the `yes/no` classes, and generate new `win` number, and finally clear the `h3` element text, like :

```js
var win = parseInt(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
var i = 1;
$('.grid-item').each(function() {
  $(this).data('slot', i++);
});

$('.grid-item').click(function() {
  if ($(this).data('slot') == win) {
    $(this).addClass('yes');
    $("H3").append("<H3>Congrats, You have won!</H3>");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('no');
  }
});

$('button').click(function() {
  $('.grid-item').each(function() {
    win = parseInt(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
    $(this).removeClass('no yes');
    $("H3").html('');
  });
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 1px;
}

.grid-item.no {
  background-image: url(https://s22.postimg.cc/yo9soxxz5/kisspng-computer-icons-x-mark-check-mark-clip-art-red-x-5ac2fb83.png);
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.grid-item.yes {
  background-image: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/papirus-team/papirus-apps/512/emerald-theme-manager-icon-icon.png);
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

H3 {
  color: green;
}

button {
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid black;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<H1>Hidden Gem Game!</H1><br/>
<div class='grid'>
  <div class='grid-item'></div>
  <div class='grid-item'></div>
  <div class='grid-item'></div><br/>
  <div class='grid-item'></div>
  <div class='grid-item'></div>
  <div class='grid-item'></div><br/>
  <div class='grid-item'></div>
  <div class='grid-item'></div>
  <div class='grid-item'></div>
</div>
<H3></H3>
<br/>
<H2>Click on the boxes to find the hidden gem.</H2>
<button type="button">Play Again</button>
```

Comment: If this answer is what you're looming for mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove yes/no classes like shown below and empty the h3 tag containing info about winning the game.

```
$('#restbtn').click( function() {
 $(".grid .grid-item").removeClass("no yes")
 $("H3").html("");
});
```

```js
var win = parseInt(Math.random() * 9) + 1
var i = 1;
$('.grid-item').each(function() {
  $(this).data('slot', i++);
});

$('.grid-item').click(function() {
  if ($(this).data('slot') == win) {
    $(this).addClass('yes');
    $("H3").append("<H3>Congrats, You have won!</H3>");


  } else {
    $(this).addClass('no');
  }
});

$('#restbtn').click(function() {
  $(".grid .grid-item").removeClass("no yes")
  $("H3").html("");
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 1px;
}

.grid-item.no {
  background-image: url(https://s22.postimg.cc/yo9soxxz5/kisspng-computer-icons-x-mark-check-mark-clip-art-red-x-5ac2fb83.png);
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.grid-item.yes {
  background-image: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/papirus-team/papirus-apps/512/emerald-theme-manager-icon-icon.png);
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

H3 {
  color: green;
}

button {
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid black;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hidden Gem!</title>



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <H1>Hidden Gem Game!</H1><br/>
  <div class='grid'>
    <div class='grid-item'></div>
    <div class='grid-item'></div>
    <div class='grid-item'></div><br/>
    <div class='grid-item'></div>
    <div class='grid-item'></div>
    <div class='grid-item'></div><br/>
    <div class='grid-item'></div>
    <div class='grid-item'></div>
    <div class='grid-item'></div>
  </div>
  <H3></H3>
  <br/>
  <H2>Click on the boxes to find the hidden gem.</H2>


  <button type="button" id="restbtn">Play Again</button>



  <script src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```